# Receiving memory leaks when editing strings

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks, console-application

```
string Player::CalcAsteroid(int _mass)
{
vector<BaseObject*>* tempObjects = GameState::GetObjects();

asteroid = "";

SetRadius(_mass / 100);
if (_mass < 100)
    SetRadius(1);

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Nested for loops to draw a circle (asteroid)
///////////////////////////////////////////////

// x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1

Player* p = dynamic_cast<Player*> ((*tempObjects)[0]);
int asteroidRadius = p->GetRadius();
double consoleRatio = 4.0 / 3.0; // Console characters do not have uniform H and W, so lets store the console ratio (4:3)
double a = consoleRatio*asteroidRadius; // The width is shorter than the height, so we'll multiply the ratio to the X radius (a)
double b = asteroidRadius; // The height need not change from the init radius

// Loop though each row...
for (int y = (int)-asteroidRadius; y <= asteroidRadius; y++)
{
    // and each column.
    for (int x = (int)floor(-consoleRatio*asteroidRadius); x <= consoleRatio*asteroidRadius; x++)
    {
        double d = (x / a)*(x / a) + (y / b)*(y / b); // Equation of a circle (see above)
        if (d > 0.90 && d < 1.1)
        {
            asteroid += (char)178; // The solid border (using gradient ASCII code)
        }
        //else if (d <= 1.1)
        //{
            //asteroid += 176; // The fill interior
        //}
        else
        {
            asteroid += " ";
        }
    }
    asteroid += '\n';
}
asteroid.replace(asteroid.size() / 2 - (name.size() / 2), name.size(), name); // Putting the name of the player in the center of the asteroid.
return asteroid;
}
```

So I am attempting to re-size the player's object (an asteroid) in console. However I seem to be getting memory leaks, a ton actually. Each seems to be related to this function call. 
`SetPicture(CalcAsteroid(GetMass()).c_str());`
The definition of which being here

`void SetPicture(const char * const _picture){ picture = _strdup(_picture);CalcWH(); }`

CalcWH(); simply calculates the width and height of the image in characters for collision data.

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sc8y5uymufo268u/Reversed%20Asteroids.zip?dl=0) link for full solution.

Thank you all in advance! Let me know if there is anything I can do to make my question more clear or whether or not I have enough information. I'm new to this site and I wish to follow good question habits.

Comment: What's the type for `asteroid`, std::string or char *?

Comment: I don't understand why a function called `CalcAsteroid` would return a string.

Comment: I suggest you split up the `SetPicture` call into multiple statements using temporary variable.  Next, single step through these statements verifying the the contents of the variables are correct. Or add code to validate the values in the temporary variables.

Comment: asteroid is a string. And the function calculates the size of the asteroid based on the Player's mass, so I pass the function my mass and it returns my newly calculated asteroid image. (using strings for images because I'm using c++/console)

Comment: Division is expensive.  You should calculate `x/a` into temporary variable.  Same with `x/b`.  Although the compiler may reuse the value in a temporary variable (register), I think it would be better to be explicit.

Comment: Noted, thanks! And I split the call into multiple statements and put a break point on the top one. Watching the data shows that everything is correct. My hunch is that something must be getting left behind when the asteroid is re-sized. It's just strange as I have never had memory leaks due to strings before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for a memory leak is the usage of `_strdup`.  This allocates memory for the new string.  It is your responsibility to free the memory using `free` somewhere in your code.  According to the code you posted, you are not calling `free` anywhere.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc.aspx

As noted by the above link:

*The _strdup function calls **malloc** to allocate storage space for a copy of strSource and then copies strSource to the allocated space.*

---

My advice is to get out of the business of calling `_strdup`, and just use a `std::string`.   There is little reason for a C++ application to use functions such as `strdup`.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. My professor never mentioned that when writing that however. Looking at my code compared to his and my classmates show no use of the `free` keyword. But in that case it is probably due to my dynamic picture compared to their static images. I'll see if your method works.

Comment: Yup! removing `_strdup` fixed the leaks! I'll ask my professor more about this. I'm still confused as to why he used it in the first place.

Comment: Your professor needs to get with the program and teach C++ or at least know what the consequences and impact of using a function such as `strdup` are.  You now have a set of students producing leaky code.

Comment: yea, I lost 40 points combined on the last 2 turn ins due to those same memory leaks. I'm going to have a word with him about it. I have to ace my final if I want a shot at a 90. I've never struggled so much to get an A in a programming class.